# .htaccess and Symfony 5 in hosted environment in subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, routes

I am yet again trying to debug my mess of .htaccess files, this time in a Symfony 5 app.

## The situation

On my domain `example.com`, I have the folder structure

```
/public_html
    /.htaccess
    /some_smaller_project
    /my_symfony_project
        /.htaccess
        /public
            /.htaccess
            /index.php
            /bundles
                /easyadmin
                    /app.css
                    /...
        /config, vendor, src, etc.
    /wp-admin
    /...
```

The site is in a hosted environment, i.e. I can't access the server settings directly but have to use .htaccess.

The file `my_symfony_project/config/routes/annotations.yaml` contains

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: /my_symfony_project
kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

The file `my_symfony_project/.htaccess` contains

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_symfony_project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [QSA, L]
```

The file `my_symfony_project/public/.htaccess` is [the default htaccess](https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/blob/master/symfony/apache-pack/1.0/public/.htaccess) installed by the symfony/apache recipe.

## The problem

The requests for example.com/my_symfony_project and example.com/my_symfony_project/some_route that are defined in my Controller classes work just fine, but the assets just return 404 codes.

Among the requests that throw 404 are:

```
example.com/bundles/easyadmin/app.css
example.com/bundles/easyadmin/app.js
example.com/_wdt/8b8d34
```

So why do EasyAdmin and the Symfony Debug Toolbar look for assets at the wrong place? And how can I avoid other problems of the same type?

I promise I have searched for solutions to exactly this problem, but most places are either giving quick snippets for an htaccess file or assume access to http.conf

Comment: have you taken a look at the symfony docs and/or installed the apache pack? https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: @Jakumi Yes, I have. I should have mentioned that. The apache pack does exactly one thing: puts the .htaccess file I mentioned into public/ . The server docs give a lot of tips in how to configure the server, but they either assume full control or adress other problems. It seems like the basic assumption is that DocumentRoot is right in the symfony project.

Comment: which - in fact - should be achievable to some degree. this is actually more of a serverfault question and you might find better help there...